# pandas read sql db2 corrupts decimal

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I am trying to read a datatable from using db2. It seems, however, that decimals are simply ignored and floats are somehow multiplied by `100`. For instance `100.50` becomes `10050.0` when read into a pandas dataframe.

BTW I am from Norway, so decimals are denoted by a `,` rather than a `.`. I dont know if this matters.

I use the following SQL (in WinSQL Lite):

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, FUND_NAME, SAVINGS_AMOUNT
FROM SAVINGS_TABLE
WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = 1
```

, which gives:

```
CUSTOMER_ID, FUND_NAME, SAVINGS_AMOUNT
          1    ASSET_X       259131,72
          1    ASSET_Y       718533,33
```

I know this is correct, so the issue is not the data.

In Spyder, using Python, I have

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc as po

DSN = 'MY_DSN'
UID = 'MY_USER'
PWD = 'MY_PASSWORD'
CON = po.connect('DSN={0}; UID={1}; PWD={2}'.format(DSN, UID, PWD))

SQL = """SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, FUND_NAME, SAVINGS_AMOUNT
FROM SAVINGS_TABLE
WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = 1"""

df = pd.read_sql(SQL, CON)

df
Out[16]: 
    CUSTOMER_ID    FUND_NAME    SAVINGS_AMOUNT
0             1      ASSET_X        25913172.0
1             1      ASSET_Y        71853333.0
```

What is happening here, and how can I fix it?

The column `SAVINGS_AMOUNT` is `DECIMAL` with `Size=9` and `Scale=2`. Surely the issue is somehow related to this. I guess I have to set a parameter in `pd.read_sql` to interpret the column.

I know I can simply divide by `100` to correct this. But I dont want to do that. I want to read the correct numbers.

Also I'm using Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find it helps to explicitly set the decimal separator to one used in Norway

```
pyodbc.setDecimalSeparator(',')
```

Comment: Thank you. I will give this a try.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you've tried forcing the SQL input:

```
SQL = """SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, FUND_NAME, Cast(SAVINGS_AMOUNT AS Decimal(20,2))
FROM SAVINGS_TABLE
WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = 1"""
```

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply. This probably works. The problem is that I have to know the format the data is stored in. There is a bunch of tables in the relevant database, and different precisions are used on different tables.

Answer (score 3):

In `read_csv` you can specify the decimal separator, but you cannot do this in `read_sql`.  Your locale may not be set correctly.  Before `read_sql`, try this:

```
import locale
locale.set_locale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, "no_NO")
```

Alternatively, if that isn't working, you could try casting the problematic column as a string in your SQL query, and then doing a `.replace` to convert the comma to a period and then finally converting it back to a number. This doesn't require you to know the precision beforehand.

Comment: Hi, thanks. It seems Python doesn't respond to `set_locale` but `setlocale`. For some reason I get `Error: unsupported locale setting`. I will see if I can get it to work.

Comment: In Windows it seems to be `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, "no")`.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried setting `pd.read_sql(SQL, CON, coerce_float=false)`? This maybe be an issue of attempting to change decimal to float.

See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.read_sql.html

EDIT:

If that does not work, you can try casting the int to a string in SQL, and then once in Python, replace the comma with a decimal and cast to float. A rather resource intensive answer, but it gets the job done.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the suggestion. This seems to cast the whole thing to int, but it still doesn't give the right answer. I.e. if the answer is 123.45 this gives 12345. :(

Comment: Hmmm.. The only other thing I can thing of is casting everything to a string in sql, then once in Python, replace the comma with a decimal and then cast to float. This would be a costly process, but would likely yield the desired result.

Comment: Hi, casting to string and then converting back to float actually works. I had to write "select varchar(SAVINGS_AMOUNT) ...". It's not pretty, but it is the only suggested solution that doesn't require that I know the precision beforehand. If you modify your answer I'll check this of as "correct".

Comment: @mortysporty May not be pretty, but I'm glad it works!

Comment: agreed! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Please try this. It may work.

```
import numpy as np
np.round(p_table, decimals=2)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I know how to "solve" this by coding. I don't want to do this. Because that requires that I know the precision of the underlying data. There are hundreds of tables and thousands of columns, with different precision in the databases I work on, and I dont want to keep track of all of them,